# Unable to get Item Id in magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have created an event called sales_order_place_after.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
 foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
     $ProdustIds[]= $item->getProductId();
 $Price[]= $item->getPrice();
  $QuoteIds[]= $item->getQuoteItemId();
  $ItemIds[]= $item->getItemId();
 }
```

Here i am getting price, product id, quote id. But Unable to get Item id , Item id is returning null .

**Is there any way to get Item Id ?**

Comment: try this $ItemIds[]= $item->getId();

Comment: For what Purpose you need ItemId ?

Comment: I need to store item id on custom table, i want to find taxes on that item id.

Answer (score 1):

Primary id should get like below

```
$ItemIds[]= $item->getId();
```

OR

```
$ItemIds[]= $item->getData('item_id');
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach ($orderItems as $key => $item){
        echo $item->getProductId();
}
```

Product itself Item Id.

Comment: I need Item id..

Comment: Product id and item id is different. One product id having multiple item ids. Its assign when we placing a order.